# Adding a class with a delay once in view

Tags: jquery, settimeout

How would I add a delay effect to the following? It's adding the 'play' class inViewport but I also want to add a delay for each instance of that, so they are fading in one at a time even when both in view.

```
;(function($, win) {
 $.fn.inViewport = function(cb) {
 return this.each(function(i,el){
   function visPx(){
     var H = $(this).height(),
         r = el.getBoundingClientRect(), t=r.top, b=r.bottom;
     return cb.call(el, Math.max(0, t>0? H-t : (b<H?b:H)));  
   } visPx();
   $(win).on("resize scroll", visPx);
    });
 };
}(jQuery, window));

$(".statement-block").inViewport(function(px){
if(px) $(this).addClass("play") ;
});
```

Comment: You tagged your question with setTimeout, but I don't see any attempt at using it. Also, why aren't you using the intersection observer instead of measuring the viewport yourself?

Comment: I do not know JS very well (I'm a designer trying to add some animation to a project on clients request). But I know how to Google and found out setTimeout is likely what I need, but I don't know how to implement it within the current code.

Comment: Did you try wrapping the if statement in the second last line in setTimeout() function?

Comment: Surely the whole point of your `inViewport` is that it will only add the class once it comes into the viewport - so if you have 2 appear at the same time, then a setTimeout might be appropriate, but if you have 1 appear then another appear shortly after while the first is still appearing, using setTimeout would not work.  You need a queue across multiple elements.